# A sum involving Logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, asymptotics

I am wondering if a closed form for the following sum exists:

$$S(N,a)=\frac{1}N\sum_{n=1}^N n\, \log\Big(1-\frac{n-a}N\Big),\qquad 0<a<1.$$

If I feed it to Mathematica, it gives me some complex expression (in terms of derivatives of Zeta functions), though the sum is real. I can easily access its asymptotics $N\rightarrow\infty$ (i.e. $S(N\gg1,a)\simeq -\frac{3}4N+\mathcal{O}(\log N)$), but given the fact that this sum does not look that complicated, I can't help but think that a closed form may exist...

Answer (score 1):

The obvious first step is to write it as
$$ \eqalign{\frac{1}{N} \log \left( \prod_{n=1}^N \left(1 - \frac{n-a}{N}\right)^n \right)
&= \frac{1}{N} \log\left(N^{-N(N+1)/2} \prod_{n=1}^N (a - n + N)^n \right)\cr
&= - \frac{N+1}{2} \log(N) + \frac{1}{N} \log\left(\prod_{n=1}^N (a - n + N)^n \right)}$$
The product is a polynomial in $a$ of degree $N(N+1)/2$ with roots of multiplicity $n$ at $n-N$.  I see no reason for that to have a "simpler" closed form.